# Is it advantageous to split parts of large time-based tables and store in separate data files?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, architecture, filegroups

On Microsoft SQL Server, I have large (multi-gigabyte) time-based tables for which I want to periodically age out and archive older data (say at the end of each year drop everything 5 years or older).

I've horizontally-partitioned the tables into separate tables by time range.

Currently my database has only 1 filegroup.  I'm wondering if there is any advantage to introducing multiple filegroups (say one for each year of data), not for performance of joins or anything but as a way of organizing data on disk or if this just adds complexity without benefit. (As should be obvious I'm not a DBA!)

I haven't tried anything yet.  I don't want to restructure my database unnecessarily.

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to include the version and edition of SQL Server you are using. Also, providing more detail about your requirements or data usage patterns will lead to more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is any advantage to introducing multiple filegroups

The only reason to do this is if you have different tiers of storage that you want map your partitions to.  For example, you have 1TB of fast storage and 10TB or slow storage, and you know that some partitions are accessed much more than others.

You don't need multiple filegroups for rolling window partitioning, or for switching partitions between tables.  It works fine with all partitions on a single filegroup.